# Finite difference and average on last n rows of postgresql column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table 'Rolls' in Postgres where a column 'A' stores 10000 records each of type SMALLINT.
I am looking to write a SQL query which will take the last 100 rows of 'Rolls' and then take the first order difference of the column and then will return the average.

For example:-

```
    Rolls 
|  A  | ---- |
   1
   2
   3
   5
   7
```

The first order difference of the last 4 rows of A is equal
[2, 2 , 1] or [(7-5), (5 - 3), (3 - 2)]
The final answer will be (2+2+1)/4 or 1.25

Is this possible to be executed in Postgresql?

Comment: This should be possible. how do you determine order in this dataset? Is there a date column or an incrementing id or something?

Comment: Yes, I also thought the order of the lines is needed. If the rows of column "A" incrementally increase, then my answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Rolls (
    "A" SMALLINT
);


INSERT INTO Rolls ("A") VALUES    
 (1),
 (4),
 (7),
 (9),
 (10),
 (12),
 (15),
 (20),
 (23)
;
```

Without calculating the average value. Used by `LAG` to take the previous row.

```
SELECT *,
"A" - LAG("A")  OVER (ORDER BY "A") AS diff 
FROM Rolls
;
```

Output

```
 A  | diff
----+------
  1 |
  4 |    3
  7 |    3
  9 |    2
 10 |    1
 12 |    2
 15 |    3
 20 |    5
 23 |    3
```

The first subquery considers the difference in "A". The second selects the last five rows. And the external query considers the average.

The `ORDER BY "A" DESC` sort is used to sort the rows in the desired order and take the desired five rows `LIMIT 5`.

```
SELECT AVG(diff)
FROM
(SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT *,
"A" - LAG("A")  OVER (ORDER BY "A") AS diff 
FROM Rolls) t
ORDER BY "A" DESC
LIMIT 5
) y
;
```

Output

```
        avg
--------------------
 2.8000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

First `cte` to add IDs using the window function `row_number()`, `cte2` to get last n rows, then we calculate the differences using `LEAD`, then latest step we calculate the average using `sum(diff)/count(1)`:

```
with cte as (
  select A, row_number() over () as row_id
  from Rolls
),
cte2 as (
  select *
  from cte
  order by row_id desc
  limit 4 
),
cte3 as (
  select A, A - LEAD(A) OVER(ORDER BY row_id desc) AS diff
  from cte2
)
select ROUND(cast(SUM(diff) as decimal)/count(1), 2)
from cte3
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XjjApDLn)

Answer (score 0):

If we apply a little bit of math, I think we can simplify the calculation.

You have values *a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n-1</sub>, a<sub>n</sub>*

The first order difference gives of the last *x* terms give:

*a<sub>n</sub>-a<sub>n-1</sub>, a<sub>n-1</sub>-a<sub>n-2</sub>, ..., a<sub>n-(x-3)</sub>-a<sub>n-(x-2)</sub>, a<sub>n-(x-2)</sub>-a<sub>n-(x-1)</sub>*

The sum of which is:

*a<sub>n</sub>-a<sub>n-1</sub> + a<sub>n-1</sub>-a<sub>n-2</sub> + ... + a<sub>n-(x-3)</sub>-a<sub>n-(x-2)</sub> + a<sub>n-(x-2)</sub>-a<sub>n-(x-1)</sub>*

As you can see almost all terms appear once as a positive and once as a negative, so the whole thing just becomes

*a<sub>n</sub>-a<sub>n-(x-1)</sub>*

So the value you actually want becomes:
*(a<sub>n</sub>-a<sub>n-(x-1))/x</sub>*

With SQL and *x=4* this becomes

```sql
select 
    (
        a - lead(a,(4 - 1)) over (order by id desc)
    )/4.0 avg
from rolls
order by id desc
limit 1
```

This assumes an `id` column, for specifying the order.
If `a` is to be taken in descending order, just replace all occurences of `id` with `a`.

And of course, for *x=100* you should replace `4` with `100`.

This finally also assumes that there are enough row.
If there aren't you have to come up with your own rules, what should happen.

[db-fiddle to play with](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/upioVv3Tq6toje75QH7BNi/0).